# Python check Internet connection for Scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, breakpoints

I'm creating a Web-Scraper. For that i want to add a function that for each Time the Scraper runs after the Sleep Function, it should check if a Internet connection is available, and when that is the Case, it should continue with the next Scrape and that should continue until I stop the scraper.

At the following Code below I tried to add the Function. When i Debug the Code it jumps to the Breakpoints, but it is breaking when there is no Internet connection.

**Code**

```
import time
import smtplib
import lxml
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
from datetime import datetime
import os.path

INTERVAL = 10
INTERVALTIMEOUT = 1


def checkInternetRequests(url='http://www.google.com/', timeout=3):
    try:
        #r = requests.get(url, timeout=timeout)
        r = requests.head(url, timeout=timeout)
        print('Connection funktioniert')
        print(r)
        return True
    except requests.ConnectionError as ex:
        print(ex)
        return False


def supremeJostensGoldRing():

    URL = 'https://stockx.com/de-de/supreme-jostens-world-famous-champion-ring-gold'
    NAME = 'Supreme Jostens Gold Ring'

    headers = {
        "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36'}

    file_exists = os.path.isfile("Supreme_Jostens_Gold_Ring.csv")
    if not file_exists:
        with open('Supreme_Jostens_Gold_Ring.csv', 'w+') as f:
            f.write('ID,Datum,Uhrzeit,Datum mit Uhrzeit,Preis\n')

    with open('Supreme_Jostens_Gold_Ring.csv', 'r+') as csv_file:
        fieldnames = ['ID', 'Datum', 'Uhrzeit', 'Datum mit Uhrzeit', 'Preis']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(
            csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames, lineterminator='\n')
        entry = len(csv_file.readlines())

        page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
        search_for_class = soup.find_all(
            'div', class_="sale-value")
        print(search_for_class)

        x = str(soup.find('div', class_="sale-value"))
        preis = str(re.sub("<.*?>", "", x))

        datum = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
        uhrzeit = datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        dateTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        new_line = '\n'

        print(NAME)
        print(preis)
        print(datum)
        print(uhrzeit)
        print(dateTime)
        print(new_line)

        writer.writerow({
            'ID': entry,
            'Datum': datum,
            'Uhrzeit': uhrzeit,
            'Datum mit Uhrzeit': dateTime,
            'Preis': preis
        })
        csv_file.flush()
        entry += 1



# while checkInternetRequests() == True:
#     nikeAirRubberDunkOffWhiteGreenStrike()
#     nikeCourtPurple()
#     supremeJostensGoldRing()
#     time.sleep(INTERVAL * 60)

if checkInternetRequests() == True:
    supremeJostensGoldRing()
    time.sleep(INTERVAL * 60)
else:
    if checkInternetRequests() == False:
        try:
            checkInternetRequests()
            if checkInternetRequests == True:
                supremeJostensGoldRing()
                time.sleep(INTERVAL * 60)
        except ValueError as err:
            print(err)
```

Comment: why not just use a `try` and handle the error instead of checking every time before you scrape?

Comment: @TenaciousB At the checkInternetRequests function I catch the Error, and print it, but I want that when there is no Internet Connection, the Scraper should Pause for a limited Time before it checks again if then the Internet works.

Comment: so `while checkInternetRequests() == True:` is going to stop if it is not true, what I am saying is put a `try` on your scraping function call in an infinite `while` loop in the `except` put the sleep